# elastic search score base length character

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Query 1 :

```
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "abcdef",
    "type": "best_fields",
    "fields": [
      "email"
    ]
  }
```

and result is right:

```
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 4.6334114,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_score": 4.6334114,
        "_source": {
           "id": 244,
           "email": "abcdef@xxxxx.com",
        }
     }
  ]
 }
```

but Query 2:

```
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "abc",
    "type": "best_fields",
    "fields": [
      "email"
    ]
  }
```

and result is :

```
  "total": 0,
  "max_score": null,
  "hits": []
```

How to custom score to Query 2 get result same Query 1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to know how your terms are indexed, for instance your email (if you're using default settings) is emitting these tokens:

- `abcdef`
- `xxxxx`
- `com`

That's why when you're querying with `"abcdef"` as a phrase, you're getting a match.

Now you could use analyzer, which would use [Edge NGram filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) (or [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)). So your email would emit such tokens:

- `abc`
- `abcd`
- `abcde`
- `abcdef`
- `abcefg`
  ...
- `com`

You would have to index your emails using this [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) and then your `abc` phrase would find a match